# Handling input models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `ViewModel` which holds my `InputModel` as a property.

I use HTML helpers like so: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InputModel.UserId)` for example.

The problem is that this generates: `<input name="InputModel.UserId" />`

And the model-binder does not populate the properties in my `HttpPost` method:

`public ActionResult Index(InputModel model)`

I see there is a generic version of HTML helpers, I was thinking maybe I can leverage that somehow, but I havn`t yet figured out how. Or maybe there is a completley different way around this, that I'm not seeing since I am new to MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either change your action to

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
```

in which case the model.InputData would be populated or use Bind attribute

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="InputModel")] InputModel model)
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with the second suggestion and it works great.